# Mi aplicación da el error android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: java, android

No tengo ni la menor idea de por qué.

Aquí os dejo mis lineas de código. He intentado todo, he leído mucho y no hay manera.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.piete.pruebas;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText etID,etTemp,etHu,etPres;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        etID=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PrimerCampo);
        etTemp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.temp);
        etHu=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hu);
        etPres=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pres);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new ConsultarDatos().execute("http://XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX?id="+etID.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }

    private class ConsultarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JSONArray ja = null;
            try {
                ja = new JSONArray(result);
                etTemp.setText(ja.getString(1));
                etHu.setText(ja.getString(2));
                etPres.setText(ja.getString(3));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        Log.i("URL",""+myurl);
        myurl = myurl.replace(" ","%20");
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("respuesta", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.piete.pruebas.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PrimerCampo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="122dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="148dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hu"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="226dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pres"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="111dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="306dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Te funciono la solución propuesta?, si es así, no olvides aceptar la respuesta, para que la pregunta no quede abierta, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas intentando hacer un cast de un `TextView` a `EditText`. Por lo que te causa:

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText

En tu `axml` tienes definido `TextView` y al hacer `findViewById` haces un cast a `EditText`.

### Solucion

En tu Activity simplemente reemplaza `EditText` por `TextView`, por ejemplo:

`etID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PrimerCampo);`

Y la variables globales también deben ser de tipo `TextView`.

**Nota:** `TextView` no puede convertirse a `EditText` porque `EditText` hereda de TextView, sin embargo, `EditText` si puede convertirse en un `TextView` mediante un cast explicito.